# Suppress output from QNMinimizer

Tags: java, output, stanford-nlp

I am using QNMinimizer in my Java code and in some cases, I want to supress the output produced by the minimize function (I assume system.err.printl is used).

I haven't found a switch on the object or a constructor or method-overload to do that.

Does anyone know if and how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own code, you can call

```
qnMinimizer.shutUp();
```

and it won't print anything.

But if you're at the command-line, most of the higher level tools that use QNMinimizer don't provide an option that allows you to do this.

One of these days we'll summon up enough energy to move to logging.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what it says. Shame on me, for not having found that myself.